# Subsequent pages not working in AJAX pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have pieces of code for creating AJAX pagination.

I am fetching data from a custom field. Since there is no way of referencing it here, I assigned it to a PHP variable for the sake of following the flow of my code.

It's important to say I am still learning Javascript so please bear with me.

The problem:

Only the first page works. I can successfully navigate to the subsequent pages but they do not return any data.

My homepage.php

```
<?php

$games = "Netherlands - Eredivisie#Go Ahead Eagles|21:00|Fortuna Sittard|||% #Africa - CAF Champions League#Kedus Giorgis|01:00|Al Ahly|Ethiopia|Egypt|% #Africa - Africa Women Cup of Nations Qualification#Burundi Women|14:00|Ethiopia Women|Burundi|Ethiopia|% Central African Republic Women|15:00|Mali Women|Central African Republic|Mali|% Tunisia Women|15:00|Niger Women|Tunisia|Niger|% Congo DR Women|16:30|Benin Women|Congo DR|Benin|%";

$matches = str_replace("|% ", "|%", $games);

preg_match_all("@[A-z0-9 ./'áàâäãåǻăāąấấặắǎȧạàãáćĉċčççďđḑḋḍdéèêëĕěēęėềẽȩẹéĝğġģǧǵḡĥħȟḣḥḩíìîïĭїĩīįǐĪỊ̣iỊǏĨị̣ịıíĵķǩḱḳļľŀĺĺóòôöõðőŏōỏǒǫȯoøồớòóõöñńņňŉŋǹṅṇŕŗřṙṛśŝşšṡṣşșţťŧțṫṭtúùûüůūűųũŭǔǘǚǜụuưüúŵŷýÿўỹẏỳỵyẙȳẙźżžẑẓḅḟḿṁṃṕṗṽṿḷẁẃẅẉẘẘẋẍÒÓÔÕÖŐǑǪŌȮØÙÚÛǓǗǙǛŨŮŰŲÜỤŪĆĈČÇÀÁÂÃÄÅẠĄĀȦǍÈÉÊËĖĘĚẸẼĒȨḾṀṂŚŜŞŠṠṢŹŻŽẐẒŃŅŇṄṆÑǸḢḤḨĤȞĹĻĽĿŢŤṪṬŖŘṘṚĜĠĢǦǴḠẀẂẄẈŴḊḌḐĎĐÐṔṖĶǨḰḲẊẌṼṾỴỸỲẎŸȲŶÝĴȷḄḞḶŁłÏÎÍÌıİßıs-]+#[^#]+@", $matches, $all_matches);

$results = [];
foreach ($all_matches[0] as $c) {
    $c = explode("#", $c);
    $country_name = $c[0];
    $results[$country_name] = [];
    $params = explode("%", $c[1]);
    foreach ($params as $param_line) {
        if (!$param_line) {
            continue;
        }
        $results[$country_name][] = explode("|", trim($param_line, '|'));
    }
}

// Number of items to display per page
$itemsPerPage = 2;
$current_page = 1;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <!-- Include your CSS and JavaScript libraries here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="matches-container">
        <?php
        // Loop through the results for the current page
        $count = 0;
        // Loop through the results for the current page
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($results as $country_name => $params) {
                $league = explode(" - ", $country_name, 2);
                $country = (isset($league[0]) ? $league[0] : '');

                $start_index = ($current_page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

                if ($count >= $start_index && $count < ($start_index + $itemsPerPage)) {
                    echo '<button>' . $country_name . '</button>';
                    echo '<table width="30px" colspan="10px" border="1px solid black">';
                    foreach ($params as $param_line) {
                        $param_line[0] = (isset($param_line[0]) ? $param_line[0] : '');
                        $param_line[1] = (isset($param_line[1]) ? $param_line[1] : '');
                        $param_line[2] = (isset($param_line[2]) ? $param_line[2] : '');
                        $param_line[3] = (isset($param_line[3]) ? $param_line[3] : '');
                        $param_line[4] = (isset($param_line[4]) ? $param_line[4] : '');
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' . $param_line[0] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $param_line[1] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $param_line[2] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $param_line[3] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $param_line[4] . '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
                }

                $count++;
            }

        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Pagination links -->
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
        $total_pages = ceil(count($results) / $itemsPerPage);
        for ($page = 1; $page <= $total_pages; $page++) {
            echo '<a href="#" class="pagination-link" data-page="' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Include your JavaScript libraries here -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Number of items to display per page
    var itemsPerPage = 1;

    // Function to display items for a specific page
    function displayPage(page) {
        var startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
        var endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;

        // Hide all items initially
        $("#matches-container button, #matches-container table").hide();

        // Show items for the current page
        $("#matches-container button, #matches-container table").each(function (index) {
            if (index >= startIndex && index < endIndex) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    }

    // Initial page load
    displayPage(1);

    // Handle pagination clicks
    $(document).on("click", ".pagination-link", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = parseInt($(this).attr("data-page"));
        displayPage(page);
    });
});
```

My ajax-matches.php

```
<?php

// Retrieving the page and items per page from the AJAX request
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$itemsPerPage = isset($_GET['items_per_page']) ? intval($_GET['items_per_page']) : 5; // Adjust this based on your needs

$games = "Netherlands - Eredivisie#Go Ahead Eagles|21:00|Fortuna Sittard|||% #Africa - CAF Champions League#Kedus Giorgis|01:00|Al Ahly|Ethiopia|Egypt|% #Africa - Africa Women Cup of Nations Qualification#Burundi Women|14:00|Ethiopia Women|Burundi|Ethiopia|% Central African Republic Women|15:00|Mali Women|Central African Republic|Mali|% Tunisia Women|15:00|Niger Women|Tunisia|Niger|% Congo DR Women|16:30|Benin Women|Congo DR|Benin|%";

$matches = str_replace("|% ", "|%", $games);

preg_match_all("@[A-z0-9 ./'áàâäãåǻăāąấấặắǎȧạàãáćĉċčççďđḑḋḍdéèêëĕěēęėềẽȩẹéĝğġģǧǵḡĥħȟḣḥḩíìîïĭїĩīįǐĪỊ̣iỊǏĨị̣ịıíĵķǩḱḳļľŀĺĺóòôöõðőŏōỏǒǫȯoøồớòóõöñńņňŉŋǹṅṇŕŗřṙṛśŝşšṡṣşșţťŧțṫṭtúùûüůūűųũŭǔǘǚǜụuưüúŵŷýÿўỹẏỳỵyẙȳẙźżžẑẓḅḟḿṁṃṕṗṽṿḷẁẃẅẉẘẘẋẍÒÓÔÕÖŐǑǪŌȮØÙÚÛǓǗǙǛŨŮŰŲÜỤŪĆĈČÇÀÁÂÃÄÅẠĄĀȦǍÈÉÊËĖĘĚẸẼĒȨḾṀṂŚŜŞŠṠṢŹŻŽẐẒŃŅŇṄṆÑǸḢḤḨĤȞĹĻĽĿŢŤṪṬŖŘṘṚĜĠĢǦǴḠẀẂẄẈŴḊḌḐĎĐÐṔṖĶǨḰḲẊẌṼṾỴỸỲẎŸȲŶÝĴȷḄḞḶŁłÏÎÍÌıİßıs-]+#[^#]+@", $matches, $all_matches);

$results = [];
foreach ($all_matches[0] as $c) {
    $c = explode("#", $c);
    $country_name = $c[0];
    $results[$country_name] = [];
    $params = explode("%", $c[1]);
    foreach ($params as $param_line) {
        if (!$param_line) {
            continue;
        }
        $results[$country_name][] = explode("|", trim($param_line, '|'));
    }
}

// Calculate the total number of pages
$totalPages = ceil(count($results) / $itemsPerPage);

// Calculate the offset based on the current page and items per page
$offset = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

// Loop through the results, starting from the calculated offset
$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $country_name => $params) {
    if ($i >= $offset && $i < ($offset + $itemsPerPage)) {
        // Generate the table for the current item
        $league = explode(" - ", $country_name, 2);
        $country = (isset($league[0]) ? $league[0] : '');
        ?>
        <table width="30px" colspan="10px" border="1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?=$country_name; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$param_line[0]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$param_line[1]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$param_line[2]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$param_line[3]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$param_line[4]; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

If you could help fix.

Comment: Now is the time for you to do some debugging.  What specifically "doesn't work"?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  In the PHP logs, are there any errors on the server?  In the browser's debugging tools, what is the request being made which "doesn't work"?  Does the data on that request match what you expect?  What is the server's response?  Does it match what you expect?  When you [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193), which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: I don’t see where `ajax-matches.php` gets loaded in your code.

Comment: Your server-side (homepage.php) does paging, so only outputs a single page in the HTML.  Your javascript is client-side and does paging *client-side*.  You need to pick an option - easiest (but initial-load slowest) is to output all the data in homepage.php then page it client-side (using your existing code change).   The alternative is for client-side (javascript) to make ajax calls to load each page.

Comment: Console is not returning any errors.

Comment: Simplest fix is to change `$itemsPerPage = 2;` to `$itemsPerPage = 99999;  (is there a int.max equivalent in php?) at least in the first instance so you can see what's happening.

Comment: There's also some conflict as your php is $itemsPerPage = 2, but your js is itemsPerPage = 1

Comment: The current issue i am facing now is that the code is separating the data so for example "Netherlands - Eredivisie" and "Go Ahead Eagles|21:00|Fortuna Sittard|||" are being thrown in separate pages. Unable to display that in the same table.